# Since I've downloaded Ubuntu one my Ubuntu Software Centre icon is gone

Tags: 11.10

Since I downloaded Ubuntu One my side tab for Ubuntu Software Center is missing.

Answer (score 2):

Please Open your terminal (CTRL+Alt+T) and type `software-center` and hit the ENTER key. At your launcher right click the icon and select 'Keep in Launcher'.

Answer (score 0):

Check your /usr/share/applications and ~.local/share/applications folders for the file "ubuntu-software-center.desktop". If it does not exist, do the following in terminal:

`gksu gedit`

Type in your password, and paste the following into the text document:

[Desktop Entry]

Name=Ubuntu Software Center

GenericName=Software Center

Comment=Lets you choose from thousands of applications available for Ubuntu

Exec=/usr/bin/software-center %u

Icon=softwarecenter

Terminal=false

Type=Application

Categories=PackageManager;GTK;System;Settings;

MimeType=application/x-deb;application/x-debian-package;x-scheme-handler/apt;

StartupNotify=true

X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=software-center

Save the file to either /usr/share/applications (recommended) or ~.local/share/applications. Then press Alt+F2 and type unity --replace.

Let us know if the file is back